# Detect an object in an imageview and merge with another object in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

Im developing an app where i have two images.user will touch some object on first image(for eg:nose).and then an object on the second image(eg:nose).

Now there will be button(merge button) and when user press that button i want to interchange the two touched images(ie two noses)of both images.

completely stuck at this point.

Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For detecting an image you can use Tap Gesture using which you can make your image draggable.

For merging an image You have to take all images you want to merge into a single UIView, for that checkout this snippet.

```
    + (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```